# c# Job Runs in Debug=Executable Fails

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, executable, release

I have a C# app that I inherited and it's time to do some maintenance to the code.   The coding is complete and the thing does run (from code) in config = debug. But when I do the Build in config=Release the executable crashes.   I'm a VB developer and this is pretty challenging for me.

I have targeted x86 platform.  This thing was originally deployed to a 2003 server and hasn't been touched since.  Now it's  going out to a 2008 server.  The old .msi won't run on the new machine so we created a new setup program.

When I start the executable I get an Application-Event error that looks like this

---

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Application Error

  - EventID 1000

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 100

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2015-12-21T20:18:07.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 11555

  Channel Application

  Computer XXX.XXX.com

  Security
- EventData

  XXX_Engine.exe 
  2.0.4.0 
  56784f41 
  ntdll.dll 
  6.1.7601.21732 
  4dd9f764 
  c0000005 
  0002e3c6

---

Any/all direction is appreciated.  Where do I start?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Have you tried searching about the error code? First result from search see if it helps.. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/261007

Comment: Also look like you might be having logger which gets enabled in Debug mode but might no be able to access information like "Computer name" Just guessing!!